# How to test if key is in dictionary inside another dictionary?

Tags: python, dictionary

How do I test if a key is inside a dictionary, inside another dictionary?

For example, I want it to return `True` only if 'Panic Room' is inside the 'Shane' dictionary, inside the ratings dictionary.

```
ratings={'Shane': {'Panic Room': 4, 'Avatar': 5}, 'Joe': {'Panic Room': 3}}
```

would return true, since Shane's dictionary has 'Panic Room' in it.

If I was looking for 'Avatar' with 'Joe', then it would return `False`, as there's no 'Avatar' corresponding to 'Joe'.

To read the entire dictionary, you would use:

```
print ratings
```

To read a user's ratings, you use:

```
print ratings["Shane"]
```

And to read a Movie's rating by a user, you use:

```
print ratings["Shane"]["Avatar"]
```

A simple one-line answer could really help.

I've tried:

```
if ratings["Shane"]["Avatar"] in ratings:
print "yes"
```

and

```
if ["Shane"]["Avatar"] in ratings:
print "yes"
```

but they don't seem to work.

Comment: Please provide the code you used to read the dictionary.

Comment: @ZetaRift Don't know why it's relevant, but okay.

Comment: I really don't understand how this is "too broad". A simple one-liner should do the trick.

Comment: This does it: `"Panic Room" in ratings["Shane"]`

Comment: @tdelaney Yeah it does, thanks! If it was not "on hold" I would accepted it as an answer.

Comment: Yeah, I'm surprised it was closed but no worries. BTW, you will get an exception if "Shane" isn't in the dictionary. You could do `"Panic Room" in ratings.get("Shane", {})` if you want to work with users who aren't in the dictionary.

Comment: Well looky here, I also found another way: if ratings["Shane"]["Avatar"]: Still has a KeyError if it's not in the dictionary. Maybe I could use try, or your method. Edit: I'm using your method. Thanks!

Comment: It may suit your needs but its not the same thing as testing whether the key is there. Suppose "Shane" doesn't have an "Avatar", that will raise a KeyError. Conversely, suppose "Shane" has `"Avatar":0`... `"Avatar" in ratings["Shane"]` would be `True` but `ratings["Shane"]["Avatar"]` would be `0`. It all depends on what you want!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have a data structure and you want to get information from it. An important part of your design is to figure out what you want and how to deal with errors you hit along the way. So, lets start with the data

```
>>> ratings={'Shane': {'Panic Room': 4, 'Avatar': 5}, 'Joe': {'Panic Room': 3}}
```

Now we want to see how people liked Avatar

```
>>> ratings['Shane']['Avatar']
5
>>> ratings['Joe']['Avatar']
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
KeyError: 'Avatar'
>>> ratings['Fred']['Avatar']
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
KeyError: 'Fred'
>>>
```

Lots of problems. Joe didn't rate the movie and Fred isn't even in the database. Clearly we need to refine our error handling. One option is to test user name and film name separately so that you can get a detailed error. I raise a `KeyError` like `dict` does in this example but you can do other things in the error case

```
>>> def get_rating(ratings, name, film):
...     if name in ratings:
...         if film in ratings[name]:
...             return ratings[name][film]
...         else:
...             raise KeyError("{} did not review {}".format(name, film))
...     else:
...         raise KeyError("{} did not review any films".format(name))
... 
>>> for name in ("Shane", "Joe", "Fred"):
...     try:
...         print(name, get_rating(ratings, name, "Avatar"))
...     except KeyError as e:
...         print(e)
... 
Shane 5
'Joe did not review Avatar'
'Fred did not review any films'
```

Suppose I want the average rating for films. Since `ratings.values()` are all of the per-user dicts, I can do a simple list comprehension that checks whether the film is rated and not worry about exceptions

```
>>> avatar = [userrate["Avatar"] for userrate in ratings.values()
...     if "Avatar" in userrate]
>>> avatar
[5]
>>> average = sum(avatar)/len(avatar)
>>> average
5.0
```

Yet another option is to use default values with the `dict.get` method. Here, if the user doesn't exist, I feed an empty film rating `dict` and if the film doesn't exist in the `dict` I give a default answer

```
>>> for name in ("Shane", "Joe", "Fred"):
...     print(name, ratings.get(name, {}).get("Avatar", "Not rated"))
... 
Shane 5
Joe Not rated
Fred Not rated
```

These are some of the common way to deal with nested dicts and as you can see, which option is best depends on your goal for a given task.